# Getting variables from scanf and cin

Tags: c++, iostream

I am new to C, so my question may be stupid. I am sorry.

I get two integers on one line divided by space. For example `3 4`. I can store them easily using this `scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);` to variables N and M. My question is: is it possible to do the same thing using `cin` and, if so, how? Or, how can I store these integers into two different variables using `cin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whitespace character and a newline are stream dilimeters, so it will work exactly the same way with `scanf` as it does with `std::cin`.

```
int a, b;
std::cin  >> a >> b;
std::cout << a << b;
```

> Input: 3 4
>   Output: 34

Answer (score 3):

```
cin>>N>>M;
```

but this stuff is explained in the first chapters of any decent C++ book; keep in mind that a Q&A site like StackOverflow cannot be a replacement for a C++ manual.

Comment: +1; I'd make it +2 for the QA/book/manual bit if I could.